# Is this function possible?

Tags: haskell

```
findM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> m [a] -> Maybe (m a)
```

I cannot implement it by myself. I could use some pointers

find looks like:

```
find f as = listToMaybe $ filter f as
```

so I tried:

```
findM f as = filterM f as >>= listToMaybe
```

but it doesnt work.

Comment: Sure you can!  `findM f mxs = Nothing`.  %-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  It is not possible.  However, you can write a function with the signature:

```
findM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> m [a] -> m (Maybe a)
```

The reason it is not possible is because in order to figure out if the `Maybe` has constructor `Just x` or `Nothing`, you have to get the value out of the monad.  Which means that the `Maybe` must be inside the monad at the end, since it is not possible in general to extract a value from inside a monad.  (That is the whole point of monads, after all.)

For example, given your signature to `findM`, you could write some obviously incorrect functions:

```
findM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> m [a] -> Maybe (m a)
findM = magic
anyM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> m [a] -> Bool
anyM f = isJust . findM f
extractBool :: Monad m => m Bool -> Bool
extractBool = anyM id . liftM (:[])
```

The function `extractBool` is obviously impossible, so `findM` cannot have that signature.

Here is an implementation of `findM`:

```
findM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m (Maybe a)
findM _ [] = return Nothing
findM f (x:xs) = do y <- f x
                    if y then return (Just x) else findM f xs
```

I am not sure of a simpler way to implement it -- this seems fairly clean, and it works on infinite lists.

Changing the signature from using an `m [a]` to using `[a]` makes it more useful and easier to use.  You'll quickly figure out why, if you implement both interfaces.

Comment: `findM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m (Maybe a)`    
`findM f as = filterM f as >>= return . listToMaybe` I dont think i need m [a] in that type

Comment: `liftM . find` has type `Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> m [a] -> m (Maybe a)` - notice you're missing an `m` on the predicate. tm1rbrt, your function looks better, but always executes the predicate on every element of the input list, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
findM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m (Maybe a)
findM p = foldr step (return Nothing)
 where
  step x r = do
    b <- p x
    if b then return (Just x) else r
```

This version only uses the predicate as much as it has to, whereas the `filterM` version uses it on every element. So for example:

```
ghci> let findM' p xs = filterM p xs >>= return . listToMaybe
ghci> let check x = putStrLn ("checking " ++ show x) >> doesDirectoryExist x
ghci> findM check ["test1", ".", "test2"]
checking "test1"
checking "."
Just "."
ghci> findM' check ["test1", ".", "test2"]
checking "test1"
checking "."
checking "test2"
Just "."
```

Comment: Oops, Dietrich fixed his `findM` to be the same as mine, now. Might as well keep this answer for its demonstration of the difference from the `filterM` version, though.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already demonstrated that this isn't possible, however with a further constraint you can get a very similar function.

```
findM :: (Traversable m, Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> m [a] -> Maybe (m a)
findM p xs = Data.Traverse.sequence $ dietrichsFindM p xs
```

Not every Monad has a Traversable instance, but if it does this will work.

Answer (score 0):

For the signature

```
findM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool)  -> m [a] -> m (Maybe a)
```

i suggest:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe

findM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool)  -> m [a] -> m (Maybe a)
findM f m = m >>= filterM f >>= return . listToMaybe
```

or

```
findM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool)  -> m [a] -> m (Maybe a)
findM = ((return . listToMaybe =<<) .) . (=<<) . filterM
```

for a point-free style.

Comment: Note that this definition usually isn't what you want.  filterM will run the monadic function on every element of the input list.  Usually I want a 'findM' that halts when the predicate is satisfied.